# How to allow Cross domain request in apache2

Tags: apache, cors, apache-config

This is my configuration file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName localhost:80
    DocumentRoot /var/www/XXX
    <Directory />
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/qvbn-app-web-ctrl>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When i am trying to reload apache2 iT is giving error as :

```
   Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
    Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I don't know how to enable CORS. I followed this:
http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Answer (score 85):

```
OS=GNU/Linux Debian
Httpd=Apache/2.4.10
```

Change in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
     AllowOverride all
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

Add/activate module

```
 a2enmod headers
```

Restart service

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..was stuck in this for a long time..I was trying to do this by LocationMatch and all.. but this worked like a charm

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Firefox was still blocking my CORS request. Finally I found out that ignoring a self-signed certificate on one port does not apply for another port in FF (in Chrome, it does). Only after manually starting a request on the other port and ignoring the cert there as well, FF allowed the CORS request. Best try to _avoid CORS requests to sites using self-signed certs_ (better setup a trusted cert, it is easier than getting this to work).

Answer (score 25):

First enable `mod_headers` on your server, then you can use header directive in both Apache conf and `.htaccess`.

1. enable `mod_headers`

- `a2enmod headers`

2. configure header in `.htaccess` file

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Also, restart apache after enabling the header module.

Answer (score 23):

In httpd.conf

1. Make sure these are loaded:

```html
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

2. In the target directory:

```html
<Directory "**/usr/local/PATH**">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

</Directory>

If running outside container, you may need to restart apache service.
```

Comment: This is the **only** answer in this thread that addresses pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests. Nice work!

Answer (score 7):

put the following in the site's .htaccess file (in the /var/www/XXX):

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

instead of the .conf file.

You'll also want to use

```
AllowOverride All
```

in your .conf file for the domain so Apache looks at it.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu Apache2 solution that worked for me
.htaccess edit did not work for me I had to modify the conf file.

> nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.xyz.conf

my config that worked to allow CORS Support

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName mydomain.xyz
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.xyz

        ServerAdmin support@mydomain.xyz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.xyz/public

        ### following three lines are for CORS support
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/privkey.pem

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### then type the following command

> a2enmod headers

### make sure cache is clear before trying

Comment: "make sure cache is clear before trying" THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

Enable mod_headers in Apache2 to be able to use Header directive :

```
a2enmod headers
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a lot of trouble getting this to work.  Dummy me, don't forget that old page - even for sub-requests - gets cached in your browser.  Maybe obvious, but clear your browsers cache.  After that, one can also use `Header set Cache-Control "no-store"`  This was helpful to me while testing.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, on a standard shared server hosting configuration (Namecheap) - on a non-production account with no need for security - this worked for me:

```
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Headers *
Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Methods *
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also put below code to the httaccess file as well to allow CORS using htaccess file

```
    ######################## Handling Options for the CORS
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=204]

   ##################### Add custom headers
   Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
   Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
   # Always set these headers for CORS. 
   Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age 1728000
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,C$
   Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

For information purpose, You can also have a look at this article http://www.ipragmatech.com/enable-cors-using-htaccess/ which allow CORS header.