# Configure apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 for to enable CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I've this HTML / Javascript code ....

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <!-- *** References for JQuery ... -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
        var city= "Torino";
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://www.mysite1.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php?",
          method: "GET",
          crossDomain: true,
          data: {municipality: city, distance:0}
        })
        .done(function(output) {
            alert("OK!");
        })
        .fail(function() {
          // handle error response
          alert("KO!");
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

... published here ...

```
http://www.mysite2.com/OpenProntoSoccorso/WebMapping/test2.html
```

In the web server (Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04) http://www.mysite1.org/.... I've modified my apache2.conf file in this way ....

```
<Directory /var/www/cesarefortelegram>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

following these instructions [How to allow Cross domain request in apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150384/how-to-allow-cross-domain-request-in-apache2).

I've still the following error in my web browser console (Network tab ..)

```
Failed to load http://www.mysite1.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorso/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php?&municipality=Torino&distance=0: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mysite2.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've found that there was an error in my apache2.conf file ....

This is the right configuration (forgot "html" after "www" .. sorry ...) ...

```
<Directory /var/www/html/cesarefortelegram>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride all
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

All works fine now ...

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Apache2 solution that worked for me
.htaccess edit did not work for me I had to modify the conf file.

> nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain.xyz.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName mydomain.xyz
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.xyz

        ServerAdmin support@mydomain.xyz
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.xyz/public

        ### following three lines are for CORS support
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.xyz/privkey.pem

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### then type the following command

> a2enmod headers

### make sure cache is clear before trying