# NULL data object showing in my php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, fetch, file-get-contents

I want to send the data (`'ABCDEF','23','1234567890','abc@def.com' and the image 'profile.jpg'`), into my `php`script, with the help of **FETCH** api.

My HTML:

```
<form id="details" class="form">

    Full name: <strong name="name_1">ABCDEF</strong><br><br>
    ID No:<strong name="org_number_1">23</strong><br><br>
    Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1">1234567890</strong><br><br>

    E-mail: <strong name="email_1">abc@def.com</strong><br><br>
    ID Card: <img src="profile.jpg" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><br><br>

    <button id="go" onclick="submit()"type="button" value="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

My javascript:

```
function submit(){

    var nme=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var id=document.getElementsByName("org_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var img=document.getElementsByName("image")[0].src;
    var dataString = {"name": nme, "email": email, "ID No": id, "Contact no": phone, "image": img};
    
    const dForm = document.getElementById('details');          
    dForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("database_registration.php",{
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(dataString), 
        }).then(function (response){
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text){
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.error(error);
        })
    });
 
}
```

My php:

```
<?php
      $post_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
      $data = json_decode($post_data); 
      var_dump($data);         //shows NULL
?>
```

Why is my `$data` object `NULL`? How do I fetch those data?

**EDIT:** I have also followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150384/how-to-allow-cross-domain-request-in-apache2/56297559#56297559) step

Comment: I suggest to take a look on CORS. https://enable-cors.org/index.html – I think you are missing the Allow-Origin Header.

Comment: Does it work if you submit the form normally (without AJAX)?

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry for that typo.

Comment: @Olivier Yea, didn't work that time too.

Comment: @m1crdy tried it, doesn't work

Comment: You're probably not sending anything, since you're not sending it the correct way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_a_file, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_your_own_request_object

Answer (score 2):

Why not getting your post inputs one by one and defining them each in a variable?

```php
$name = $_POST['name']
$id = $_POST['ID No']
$email = $_POST['email']
$phone = $_POST['ContactNo']
$img = $_POST['image']
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you try to contact an API on your localhost at port 5500:

```
127.0.0.1:5500
```

By default a lot of things are forbidden, you have to allow it. The server where the API is should have the CORS correctly set. You can either set them on your Apache or Nginx server, or in your app (for example NodeJS app).

- [CORS on Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297559/1098303)
- [CORS on nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)
- [CORS on Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

Answer (score 0):

The data won't be availabe in the super global variables (`$_POST` in this case) because it's not coming from a **multipart-data** form or an **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. You should be able to see the data reading `'php//input'`:

```
<?php
     $post_data = file_get_contents("php://input")
     $data = json_decode($post_data); 
     var_dump($data); //You can't echo an object
```

**MY REFACTOR**

```
<form id="details" class="form">

        Full name: <strong name="name_1">ABCDEF</strong><br><br>
        ID No:<strong name="org_number_1">23</strong><br><br>
        Mobile No:<strong name="ph_number_1">1234567890</strong><br><br>
    
        E-mail: <strong name="email_1">abc@def.com</strong><br><br>
        ID Card: <img src="profile.png" alt="preview" name="image" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><br><br>
    
        <button id="go" type="submit">Submit</button>
    
    </form>
```

```
document.getElementById('details').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            submitData();
        });

function submidData() {
    var nme=document.getElementsByName("name_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var id=document.getElementsByName("org_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var phone=document.getElementsByName("ph_number_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var email=document.getElementsByName("email_1")[0].innerHTML;
    var img=document.getElementsByName("image")[0].src;
    var dataString = {"name": nme, "email": email, "IDNo": id, "ContactNo": phone, "image": img};

    fetch("database_registration.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            body: JSON.stringify(dataString)
        }).then(function (response){
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (text){
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

**MY OUTPUT**

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'ABCDEF' (length=6)
  public 'email' => string 'abc@def.com' (length=11)
  public 'IDNo' => string '23' (length=2)
  public 'ContactNo' => string '1234567890' (length=10)
  public 'image' => string 'http://localhost/so-test/profile.png' (length=36)
```

Comment: it prints **NULL**

Comment: I was able to reproduce your code and test it after refactoring the HTML and JS part too, so I'm gonna share with you what I did to make it work.

Comment: I keep getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)`. How do I fix this? Please help me.

Comment: Well, that's brand new information. Sounds like your server doesn't allow he POST method, wich is pretty strange since it's really common. Please, share information about the server you're using and its configurations.

Comment: Well, as far as I know, I do have `XAMPP` and `php 8.0.0` installed. And my code editor is **Visual Studio Code**. That's all I know of.

Comment: Try this headers: `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}`