# has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to obtain data from a JSON, in local mode I can make it work, I have to enable a CORS extension in chrome and that's it.
Then when I have decided to upload the file to the server, on the server side with PHP, I enable the headers as follows

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>
```

y tambien en el .htaccess de la siguiente manera:

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.siteExample.com/coins/151.json?hr=100' from origin 'https://meSiteExample.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What else can I do?

Comment: Probably duplicate... you can check here for a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150384/how-to-allow-cross-domain-request-in-apache2. And another here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558221/how-to-cors-enable-apache-web-server-including-preflight-and-custom-headers

Answer (score -1):

As I read [here](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-cors-apache-web-server/), Maybe you need use:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Instead of :

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

in your .htaccess file.

**Also Remember & pay attention `'*'` will enable CORS for all websites. and it has security risks. if you know your request coming from where , you can filter that by enter domain instead of `'*'`.**

For example:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "example.com" //OR "localhost"
```

Comment: @flapeer did you restart apache after that ?

Comment: I am using hostinger.com, in cpanel I have no way to restart as far as I was seeing

Comment: So please check that where is your .httaccess located? is that located on your root path, or it's located on subfolder like `coins/` ?

Answer (score -1):

use this instead of esterik *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept